# lost server replies/errors with netty's object decoder

Tags: tcp, netty, vpn

I have a very simple netty app which serves both as server and a client.

Client uses `channel.writeAndFlush()` to send request to server and then blocks on `monitor.wait()`.

In client's InboundAdapter in `channelRead()` I find the appropriate monitor and do `monitor.notify()` to let the requesting client thread to proceed working on the server's reply.

On the server in ChannelHandler's `channelRead()` I do the following:

To limit the amount of requests being processed I submit a task which does the real work as a new task to existing EventLoop: `ctx.executor().submit(new Task())`. I that task I do heavy IO operations and after that I `writeAndFlush()` results back to client.

Here is my pipeline setup:

```
new ObjectEncoder(), 
new ObjectDecoder(LibConstants.Search.MAX_REQUIEST_SIZE, ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null))
```

Here is the bootstrap config:

```
new ServerBootstrap()
   .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
   .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1000)
   .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
```

I have 2 problems:

1. Rather often I get `io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.UTFDataFormatException` on the client when receiving a reply from server. I cannot find any obvious reason for this. Since my pipeline setup is so simple.
2. A reply from the server just wouldn't appear on the client. I the logs I see a successful flush on the server but the reply never arrived at the client. This is very hard to deal with since my app is very latency sensitive. Any timeout I would set will kill my user experience. 
   This all happens over a VPN network so there is a possibility that VPN device misbehaves in some weird way but I hoping that TCP would handle any sort of packet loss/corruption which can happen in the channel.

Any advice or experience  you can share will be very appreciated!